# Failed lookup for key in templates

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to get Specific List in Dictionary, but first I got the error: "fail to lookup for key", searching on internet I found out a tread with this solution:

```
{% with obj1.page.val2 as val2 %}
     {{ obj1.val1|default:val2 }}
{% endwith %}
```

But It does not work any help here is my code:

```
keyData = '\'' + id + '|' + id2 + '|' + id3 + '\'';
console.log(keyData);
var val2;                       

try
{      
     {% with keyData as val2 %}
         console.log(val2);
         datas = {{product_prices_complex_key|get_item:val2|safe}};
     {% endwith %}                      

     console.log(datas);
}catch(err){console.log(err);}
```

KeyData: WA5-8|2|5

And is in the dictionary.

Comment: `{% with keyData as val2 %}` is keyData a JS variable?

Comment: function buildTable($el, cells, rows, level, id, id2, id3) {
                    var i; var j; var row
                    var columns = []
                    var data = []
                    var keyData = '';
                    var datas = null; its declare at the beginning of the script in template.

Comment: If `keyData` is a JS variable then it will not work. Django will first render the template and parse all tags before any JS is run, in your case you are assigning `None` to `val2` because keyData does not exist in your context

Comment: keyData = '\'' + id + '|' + id2 + '|' + id3 + '\''; this is my variable, and has a value, in the console log it shows 'WA5-8|2|5'

Comment: @IainShelvington is right. You have a misconception about how javascript and django template tags work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn product_prices_complex_key into a JS object so that you can use it for performing your dynamic lookups. The [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) tag provides a way to do this.

This goes somewhere on your page before your script but not inside a script tag

```
{{ product_prices_complex_key|json_script:"data" }}
```

Then this data can be accessed like so

```
var product_prices_complex_key = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').textContent);
keyData = '\'' + id + '|' + id2 + '|' + id3 + '\'';
console.log(keyData);                

try
{
     datas = product_prices_complex_key[keyData];
     console.log(datas);
}catch(err){console.log(err);}
```